# SyntaxError: invalid syntax (try)

Tags: python

I'm writing a script to start all of my services like Admin and Managed Server using Python. When i tried executing it says "SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax(try). Please find the code below

```
import time
sleep=time.sleep
configFile = 
"/u02/weblogic/user_projects/domains/base_domain/userConfig.dat"
 pwFile = "/u02/weblogic/user_projects/domains/base_domain/userKey.dat"
while True:
try:
connect(userConfigFile=configFile,
userKeyFile=pwFile,
url='t3://my.Adminserver.com:7001')
break
except:
sleep(60)
nmConnect(userConfigFile=configFile,
userKeyFile=pwFile,
domainName='base_domain')
nmStart('ManageServer1')
exit()
```

Comment: You need to indent the body of the `try` clause, and you need *something* in the body of the `except` clause.

Comment: Why do you have a break in there? Is it inside of a loop? If it's not, you don't need the break

Comment: Please [edit] and add the full error message, and use code formatting please.

Comment: @MSR: Edit that into your question; don't jam it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The try/except block should have 4 spaces. Functions, classes, if statements, while loops, for loops and try/except block all get 4 spaces.

```
try:
    connect(userConfigFile=configFile,userKeyFile=pwFile,url='t3://localhost:7001')
    break
except:
```

The rest of your code which you posted has a few other things perhaps  I would change.I wouldn't set up a sleep variable like that I personally would just call time.sleep(). Also don't forget while loops gets 4 spaces of indentation and so try/except blocks.  I'm also not sure about the last 5 lines of code if they are part of the except clause but if they are space them in 8 times (the reason is because we need to get past the while loop + put the code in the except clause so 8 spaces). I would edit your code snippet in your question with the correct indentation and perhaps comment out what it is suppose to do and such.

```
import time
configFile = "/u02/weblogic/user_projects/domains/base_domain/userConfig.dat"
pwFile = "/u02/weblogic/user_projects/domains/base_domain/userKey.dat"
while True:
    try:
        connect(userConfigFile=configFile,
        userKeyFile=pwFile,
        url='t3://my.Adminserver.com:7001')
        break
    except:
        sleep(60)
nmConnect(userConfigFile=configFile,
userKeyFile=pwFile,
domainName='base_domain')
nmStart('ManageServer1')
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

A `SyntaxError` is at, or before, the `^` symbol.  So the error is going to be before the `try:` itself -- maybe a missing parenthesis on a previous line, maybe `try` is not indented correctly -- we cannot tell because you have elided all the previous code, but that's where you should look.

Comment: @MSR, the code as given in the question can't be *expected* to be valid, since it has no indentation. The code in the comment is even worse, since *no* comments have indentation, but without indentation, multi-line Python syntax isn't sufficiently complete to parse.

Comment: @Ethan, please consider a bit of chiding re: the first bullet point in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to have taken place.

Comment: @MSR, edit the question to accurately show your code's indentation, and we might have enough information to make that determination. See also the [mcve] definition in the Help Center: The code in the question should be the *shortest possible thing* with which we can generate the *exact* error you're asking about, with no changes whatsoever. (Needing to define a `connect` function, f/e, is a change).